# How to remove smart quote and emdash in PHP and replace them with space and regular dash?

Tags: php, html-entities, smart-quotes

I have a string with smart quote and emdash. I don't want to remove any other special characters. I just want to remove only these two. I want it to be displayed at some places but not in others.Tried couple of solutions but nothing worked. How should I proceed?
These are the option that I tried...

```
$pullquoteWithapos = utf8_encode($title);
$pullquoteWithapos =utf8_decode(str_replace('&#8221;','',$pullquoteWithapos));
$pullquoteWithapos = utf8_decode($pullquoteWithapos);
$pullquoteWithapos = str_replace('?', '\'',$pullquoteWithapos);
echo $pullquoteWithapos;
```

TIA

---

This is what I did which worked
    $cleanStr = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    $cleanStr =   str_replace('”','',$cleanStr); 
    $cleanStr = str_replace('—','-',$cleanStr); 
    $cleanStr = str_replace('’','\'', $cleanStr);

Comment: post what you have tried and we will help from there.

Comment: I tried this.. But it didn't work either $search = array('&#8221;','&#8212');
$replace = array('','-');
$var = str_replace($search, $replace, $var);
echo  $var;

Comment: Other code $pullquoteWithapos = utf8_encode($title);

$pullquoteWithapos = utf8_decode(str_replace('&#8221;', '', $pullquoteWithapos));
$pullquoteWithapos = utf8_decode($pullquoteWithapos);
$pullquoteWithapos = str_replace('?', '\'',$pullquoteWithapos);

Comment: might be a good chance to edit the question with the above comments.

Comment: This is what I which worked.                                                       $cleanStr = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$cleanStr = str_replace('&rdquo;','',$cleanStr);
$cleanStr = str_replace('&mdash;','-',$cleanStr);
$cleanStr = str_replace('&rsquo;','\'', $cleanStr);
return $cleanStr;